# How do i remove an li my case

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-lists

how do i remove the  text li created in the JavaScript.
the li was created in the javascript and on click on each button in front of them it should only remove that li and not all

```js
function addBook() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('books').value;
  if (userInput === "") {
    alert("Please Enter A Text");
    return false;
  }

  var book = document.getElementById('addBook');
  var list = document.getElementById('addBook').children;
  var check = -1;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'X';

  (list.length === 0) && book.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + userInput + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a></li>');

  for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    console.log(list[k].innerText);
    if (list[k].innerText === userInput + "x") {
      check = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  (check === -1) && book.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + userInput + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a></li>');
}

function removeParent(e) {
  var book = document.getElementById('addBook').children;
  book.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 form-cont">
  <h3>Favourite Books </h3>
  <caption>Enter Book's name:</caption> <input type="text" id="books" class="form-control" required="required">
  <button onclick="addBook()" class="btn btn-success">Add Book</button>
  <ol type="i" id="addBook">
  </ol>
  <h3 id="h">Hoobies</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`book` is not an `Element`, instead it is a **list of `Element`s**

Simple use `e` instead of `book`

```
function removeParent(e) {
  e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function addBook() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('books').value;
  if (userInput === "") {
    alert("Please Enter A Text");
    return false;
  }

  var book = document.getElementById('addBook');
  var list = document.getElementById('addBook').children;
  var check = -1;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'X';

  (list.length === 0) && book.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + userInput + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a></li>');

  for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    console.log(list[k].innerText);
    if (list[k].innerText === userInput + "x") {
      check = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  (check === -1) && book.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + userInput + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a></li>');
}

function removeParent(e) {
  e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 form-cont">
  <h3>Favourite Books </h3>
  <caption>Enter Book's name:</caption> <input type="text" id="books" class="form-control" required="required">
  <button onclick="addBook()" class="btn btn-success">Add Book</button>
  <ol type="i" id="addBook">
  </ol>
  <h3 id="h">Hoobies</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the removeParent function like this:

```
function removeParent(e) {
  var book = document.getElementById('addBook');
  book.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```

```js
function addBook() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('books').value;
  if (userInput === "") {
    alert("Please Enter A Text");
    return false;
  }

  var book = document.getElementById('addBook');
  var list = document.getElementById('addBook').children;
  var check = -1;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'X';

  (list.length === 0) && book.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + userInput + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a></li>');

  for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    console.log(list[k].innerText);
    if (list[k].innerText === userInput + "x") {
      check = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  (check === -1) && book.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + userInput + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a></li>');
}

function removeParent(e) {
  var book = document.getElementById('addBook');
  book.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 form-cont">
  <h3>Favourite Books </h3>
  <caption>Enter Book's name:</caption> <input type="text" id="books" class="form-control" required="required">
  <button onclick="addBook()" class="btn btn-success">Add Book</button>
  <ol type="i" id="addBook">
  </ol>
  <h3 id="h">Hoobies</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to use the "e" parameter it's directly pointing on your element that was clicked :

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" style="margin-left:10px;" onclick="removeParent(this)">x</a>
```

h

```
function removeParent(e) {   
    e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```